# What is the difference between virtio-net-pci, virtio-net-pci-non-transitional and virtio-net-pci-transitional

Tags: kvm, qemu

I am seeing multiple virtio models for -nic.

```
% qemu-system-x86_64 -nic model=help | grep virtio
virtio-net-pci
virtio-net-pci-non-transitional
virtio-net-pci-transitional
```

I want to know the difference between them. When to use what?